# deserialization issue after changing namespace to customise tag names for boost xml

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-serialization

I have made the below changes to have customised names for tags.
And the below code changes worked successfully and i could create a xml doc with customised names.

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar,std::pair<int const , Myclass::Pgroups>& p, unsigned) {
            ar & make_nvp("assetid", p.first) & make_nvp("assetdata", p.second);
        }
} }

namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar,std::pair<int const , values>& p, unsigned) {
            ar & make_nvp("hacc_groupid", p.first) & make_nvp("hacc_groupdata", p.second);
        }
} }
```

But this seems to be a problem  deserialising the xml to the object, i get boost error

```
 template<class Archive, class Object>
   std::string serialise_to_string(const char* tag,Object & obj)
   {
     std::ostringstream os (std::ios::binary);
     Archive arch ( os );
     arch << boost::serialization::make_nvp(tag,obj);
     return os.str();
   }
   template<class Archive , class Object>
   void deserialise_to_obj( std::string const  &s1,Object &outObj)
   {
      std::stringstream is( s1, std::ios_base::binary| std::ios_base::out| std::ios_base::in);
      Archive arch (is);
      arch >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("tag",outObj);
   };
```

> Without boost namespace customisation the serialisation and deserialisation are perfectly working  , but with change in boost namespace for having customised tag names , **the deserialisation has issue .**

Error with the above code , i.e  with const in namespace  arg`void serialize(Ar& ar,std::pair<int const , values>& p, unsigned)`

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp:21:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive_impl.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/basic_binary_oarchive.hpp:33:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:23:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:68:
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/check.hpp:162:5: error: static_assert failed "typex::value"
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(typex::value);
    ^                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/static_assert.hpp:70:41: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT'
#     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)
                                        ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:603:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::detail::check_const_loading<const int>' requested here
    detail::check_const_loading< T >();
            ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:66:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::load<boost::archive::xml_iarchive, const int>' requested here
        archive::load(* this->This(), t);
                 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/basic_xml_iarchive.hpp:78:39: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<boost::archive::xml_iarchive>::load_override<const int>' requested here
        this->detail_common_iarchive::load_override(t.value());
                                      ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp:95:38: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::basic_xml_iarchive<boost::archive::xml_iarchive>::load_override<const int>' requested here
        basic_xml_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(t);
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:68:23: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::xml_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::xml_iarchive>::load_override<const boost::serialization::nvp<const int> >' requested here
        this->This()->load_override(t);
                      ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:75:32: note: (skipping 45 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
        return *(this->This()) >> t;
                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/basic_xml_iarchive.hpp:78:39: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<boost::archive::xml_iarchive>::load_override<Myclass>' requested here
        this->detail_common_iarchive::load_override(t.value());
                                      ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp:95:38: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::basic_xml_iarchive<boost::archive::xml_iarchive>::load_override<Myclass>' requested here
        basic_xml_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(t);
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:68:23: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::xml_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::xml_iarchive>::load_override<const boost::serialization::nvp<Myclass> >' requested here
        this->This()->load_override(t);
```

> If const-ness is removed from the boost namespace , deserialise_to_obj and serialise_to_string functions ,the code compiles and runs without any issue but **doesn't customise the tag name**

Hope my information is clear, 
Iam stuck at an issue where iam really not sure whether the deserialisation to object can smoothly happen with customised tag names.
Please advice me what has to be done

Sample code foe serialisation and deserialisation with custom tag names  [**live at coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02c614b41782a596)

sample working code without deserialzation and custom tag names 
[**live at coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16632dc889b2d9d2)

Thanks
Tejas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cinch is in the const-ness of `std::pair<>::first` for `std::map::value_type`.

This is one of the very few cases where using `const_cast` makes sense:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template<class Ar>
        inline void serialize(Ar & ar, std::pair<int const, values> & p, unsigned) {
            ar & make_nvp("assetid", const_cast<int&>(p.first)) & make_nvp("assetdata", p.second);
        }

    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar,std::pair<int const, Myclass::Pgroups>& p, unsigned) {
            ar & make_nvp("hacc_groupid", const_cast<int&>(p.first)) & make_nvp("hacc_groupdata", p.second);
        }
} }
```

Incidentally, this is also what Boost Serialization does: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/boost/serialization/utility.hpp

#### Full Working Demo

> **Updated:** Also overrides the the `item` node name now

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0657185be987a38)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

#include <map>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>

using boost::serialization::make_nvp;

namespace MyDomain { // demonstrate ADL for serialize
    struct values
    {
        std::string name;
        std::string sex;
        values() : name("dummy"), sex("dummy") {};

        template<class Archive>   
            void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/) {
                ar & make_nvp("name", name);
                ar & make_nvp("sex", sex);
            }
    };

    struct Myclass {
        Myclass() { }

        template<class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/)  {
                ar & make_nvp("etoto", e_group);
                ar & make_nvp("ptoto", p_group);
            }

        typedef std::map<int,values> groups;
        typedef std::map<int,groups> Pgroups;    

        groups  e_group;
        Pgroups p_group;
    };

    #define CUSTOM_MAP_SERIALIZE(Map, keyname, valuename) \
    template<class Ar> inline void serialize(Ar & ar, Map::value_type& p, unsigned) { \
            ar & make_nvp(keyname, const_cast<int&>(p.first)) & make_nvp(valuename, p.second); \
        }

    CUSTOM_MAP_SERIALIZE(Myclass::groups, "assetid", "assetdata")
    CUSTOM_MAP_SERIALIZE(Myclass::Pgroups, "hacc_groupid", "hacc_groupdata")
}

namespace boost { namespace serialization {

    #define OVERRIDE_NVP(T, name) \
       template <> inline const nvp<T> make_nvp(const char *, T &t) { return nvp<T>(name, t); } \
       template <> inline const nvp<T const> make_nvp(const char *, T const &t) { return nvp<T const>(name, t); }

    OVERRIDE_NVP(MyDomain::Myclass::groups::value_type,  "group_item")
    OVERRIDE_NVP(MyDomain::Myclass::Pgroups::value_type, "Pgroup_item")

    #undef OVERRIDE_NVP
} }

template<class Archive, class Object>
std::string serialise_to_string(Object const& assetlist)
{
    auto os = std::ostringstream(std::ios::binary);
    Archive arch { os, boost::archive::no_header };
    arch << make_nvp("Main", assetlist);
    return os.str();
}


template<class Archive , class Object>
void deserialise_to_obj(std::string const &s1,Object &outObj)
{
    std::stringstream is( s1, std::ios_base::binary| std::ios_base::out| std::ios_base::in);
    Archive arch { is, boost::archive::no_header };
    arch >> make_nvp("Main", outObj);
}

MyDomain::Myclass create_data()
{
    MyDomain::Myclass object;
    MyDomain::values val1;
    object.e_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,val1) ) ;
    object.e_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,val1) ) ;
    object.p_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,object.e_group) ) ;
    object.p_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,object.e_group) ) ;   
    return object;
}

int main() {
    {
        MyDomain::Myclass obj = create_data() ;

        std::string s2 = serialise_to_string<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>(obj);

        //Save xml to a file
        {
            std::ofstream ofs("output1.xml");
            ofs << s2 << std::endl << std::endl;
            ofs.close();
        }

    }

    std::string content;
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("output1.xml");
        content.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});
        ifs.close();
    }
    {
        MyDomain::Myclass outObj;
        deserialise_to_obj<boost::archive::xml_iarchive>(content,outObj);
        //Print the object 
        for(auto &i:outObj.p_group){
            std::cout<<"\n"<<i.first<<"\n";
            for(auto &j:i.second){
                std::cout<<"\t"<<j.first<<"\t"<<j.second.name<<"\t"<<j.second.sex<<"\n";
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Prints

```
1
    1   dummy   dummy
    2   dummy   dummy

2
    1   dummy   dummy
    2   dummy   dummy
```

With output1.xml

```xml
<Main class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <etoto class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <count>2</count>
        <item_version>0</item_version>
        <group_item class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
            <assetid>1</assetid>
            <assetdata class_id="3" tracking_level="0" version="0">
                <name>dummy</name>
                <sex>dummy</sex>
            </assetdata>
        </group_item>
        <group_item>
            <assetid>2</assetid>
            <assetdata>
                <name>dummy</name>
                <sex>dummy</sex>
            </assetdata>
        </group_item>
    </etoto>
    <ptoto class_id="4" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <count>2</count>
        <item_version>0</item_version>
        <Pgroup_item class_id="5" tracking_level="0" version="0">
            <hacc_groupid>1</hacc_groupid>
            <hacc_groupdata>
                <count>2</count>
                <item_version>0</item_version>
                <group_item>
                    <assetid>1</assetid>
                    <assetdata>
                        <name>dummy</name>
                        <sex>dummy</sex>
                    </assetdata>
                </group_item>
                <group_item>
                    <assetid>2</assetid>
                    <assetdata>
                        <name>dummy</name>
                        <sex>dummy</sex>
                    </assetdata>
                </group_item>
            </hacc_groupdata>
        </Pgroup_item>
        <Pgroup_item>
            <hacc_groupid>2</hacc_groupid>
            <hacc_groupdata>
                <count>2</count>
                <item_version>0</item_version>
                <group_item>
                    <assetid>1</assetid>
                    <assetdata>
                        <name>dummy</name>
                        <sex>dummy</sex>
                    </assetdata>
                </group_item>
                <group_item>
                    <assetid>2</assetid>
                    <assetdata>
                        <name>dummy</name>
                        <sex>dummy</sex>
                    </assetdata>
                </group_item>
            </hacc_groupdata>
        </Pgroup_item>
    </ptoto>
</Main>
```

Comment: it works now,thanks , is there a way I can change the tag <item> or is it unchangable

Comment: Sure. See [that previoius answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050361/how-to-customise-default-boost-xml-serialisation-default-node-naming-to-make-it/43055862#43055862). I'm going to point at the **Disclaimer** again. You'll just be doing code duplication while you - fundamentally - don't control the archive format. Since you're LearningCpp I'd suggest renaming `item` is a good exercise for the reader?

Comment: still trying to achieve it , I tried traversing p.second in the boost namespace

Comment: It's really not that hard. I think. I just think its useless. Let me try

Comment: Added a proof of concept (most time spent cleaning it up) **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0657185be987a38)**

Comment: I would nt have had a minimum idea of doing it :) , this is excellent

Comment: The trick is to read what functions are used and what the minimum set of functions to overload. Should I repeat my [**Disclaimer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050361/how-to-customise-default-boost-xml-serialisation-default-node-naming-to-make-it/43055862#43055862) :)

Comment: Is there a need to catch the exception in serialise_to_string function or boost already has exception handling to catch the exception and print the serialization error, if there is a serialization error thrown due to the missing XML field.

Comment: Is it possible to have all items of under in a single line under assetdata tag per group_item
ex :   <assetdata>
          <name=dummy sex=dummy>
          </assetdata>

Comment: Just stop it. You're swimming against the stream. If you try to do it at length, you'll tire and the stream wins. If your life depends on it, you have already drowned.

Comment: :) :) , So its not possible ?

Comment: is there any other way using BOOST ?

Comment: No good ways. Boost does not have an XML library. Use PugiXML or Libxml2, e.g. PugiXML is/can be header only. It has MIT license, which is similar to Boost License

Comment: Thanks sehe , you are best :)

Comment: can I not do it ? Doesn't boost support it ?