# C++ serialize an object list to XML with for loop

Tags: c++, xml, for-loop, serialization, pugixml

I have an object list and wanna serialize it to xml.  My object is:

```
struct PingLogDto
{
    int PingLogID;
    int HardwareHostID;
    std::string PingLogRoundtripTime;
};
```

And here i make my list just like this:

```
vector<PingLogDto> pingLogList;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    PingLogDto pingLog;
    pingLog.HardwareHostID = 1;
    pingLog.PingLogRoundtripTime = std::to_string(i);

    pingLogList.push_back(pingLog);
}
```

And i send this list to a method which will serialize my object:

```
RequestHandler().SendPingServerLog(pingLogList);
```

And my method is:

```
void RequestHandler::SendPingServerLog(vector<PingLogDto> pingLogList)
{
    std::string xml = "";

    for (auto &pingLog : pingLogList) 
    {
        std::string docStringValue;
        PingLogDto pingLogDto;
        PingLogDtoXml::Saver saver;

        pugi::xml_document _doc;

        saver(_doc.root(), "PingLog", pingLog);

        std::stringstream ss;
        _doc.save(ss);
        docStringValue =  ss.str();
        xml += docStringValue;
    }

    std::cout<<"xml: "<<xml<<std::endl;    
}
```

In this method; i use pugixml library for serialization. Because of non-reflection language c++, i had to do this to serialize my object. Here is my old question:
[How to change or delete tags in boost serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455079/how-to-change-or-delete-tags-in-boost-serialization) And my object header like this:

```
struct PingLogDtoXml {
    struct Saver {
        template <typename T>
        void operator()(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name, T const& value) const {
            auto node = named_child(parent, name);
            node.text().set(to_xml(value));
        }

        template <typename C>
        void operator()(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name, std::string const& item_name, C const& container) const {
            auto list = named_child(parent, name);

            for (auto& item : container)
                operator()(list, item_name, item);
        }

        void operator()(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name, PingLogDto const& o) const {
            auto dto = named_child(parent, name);
            operator()(dto, "PingLogID", o.PingLogID);
            operator()(dto, "HardwareHostID", o.HardwareHostID);
            operator()(dto, "PingLogRoundtripTime", o.PingLogRoundtripTime);
        }

    private:
        template <typename T> static T const& to_xml(T const& v) { return v; }
        static char const* to_xml(std::string const& v) { return v.c_str(); }

        pugi::xml_node named_child(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name) const {
            auto child = parent.append_child();
            child.set_name(name.c_str());
            return child;
        }
    };

    struct Loader {
        void operator()(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name, std::string& value) const {
            auto node = parent.first_element_by_path(name.c_str());
            value = node.text().as_string();
        }
        void operator()(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name, int& value) const {
            auto node = parent.first_element_by_path(name.c_str());
            value = node.text().as_int();
        }

        template <typename C>
        void operator()(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name, std::string const& item_name, C& container) const {
            auto list = parent.first_element_by_path(name.c_str());

            for (auto& node : list) {
                if (node.type() != pugi::xml_node_type::node_element) {
                    std::cerr << "Warning: unexpected child node type ignored\n";
                    continue;
                }
                if (node.name() != item_name) {
                    std::cerr << "Warning: unexpected child node ignored (" << node.name() << ")\n";
                    continue;
                }

                container.emplace_back();
                operator()(node, container.back());
            }
        }

        void operator()(pugi::xml_node dto, PingLogDto& o) const {
            operator()(dto, "PingLogID", o.PingLogID);
            operator()(dto, "HardwareHostID", o.HardwareHostID);
            operator()(dto, "PingLogRoundtripTime", o.PingLogRoundtripTime);            
        }

        void operator()(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name, PingLogDto& o) const {
            operator()(parent.first_element_by_path(name.c_str()), o);
        }
    };
};
```

This struct can serialize object to xml successfully. Just for clear, here my example:

```
PingLogDto pingLog;
pingLog.HardwareHostID = 1;
pingLog.PingLogRoundtripTime = "45";
```

if i serialize this pingLog object:
    saver(_doc.root(), "PingLog", pingLog);

print will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PingLog>
    <PingLogID>0</PingLogID>
    <HardwareHostID>1</HardwareHostID>
    <PingLogRoundtripTime>45</PingLogRoundtripTime>
</PingLog>
```

My question is, when i serialize an array i got xml tags for each object. Here an example xml print:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PingLog>
    <PingLogID>0</PingLogID>
    <HardwareHostID>1</HardwareHostID>
    <PingLogRoundtripTime>0</PingLogRoundtripTime>
    <PingLogDate>123</PingLogDate>
</PingLog>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PingLog>
    <PingLogID>0</PingLogID>
    <HardwareHostID>1</HardwareHostID>
    <PingLogRoundtripTime>1</PingLogRoundtripTime>
</PingLog>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PingLog>
    <PingLogID>0</PingLogID>
    <HardwareHostID>1</HardwareHostID>
    <PingLogRoundtripTime>2</PingLogRoundtripTime>
</PingLog>
```

How can i fix this, what is my fault?

Comment: Without deeper knowledge, it seems you do output of XML docs. in a loop. Instead, you want _one_ doc with multiple nodes. For this, you have to solve another issue: An XML doc may have only one root node. Probably, you have to insert an additional root node. (This said having in mind how XML works in general as I don't know pugixml...)

Comment: Did you see [pugixml 1.8 quick start guide](https://pugixml.org/docs/quickstart.html)? I recommend especially [Modifying document data](https://pugixml.org/docs/quickstart.html#modify) as it shows how nodes are inserted into doc.

Comment: @Scheff yeah i though so. But problem is; server accepts daha in this way. If there any way to do like this, i prefer this version or i'll have to change server code too.

Comment: What about the second `saver::operator()()`? (I mean the one which accepts two node names and a container?)

Comment: I guess, the loop in `RequestHandler::SendPingServerLog()` is obsolete. Instead, you might call the `saver::operator()` with the container `pingLogList` directly. (Be aware, that this operator _does_ already contain the loop. The rest should work with "template magic"...)

Comment: @Scheff i m going with your way, i ve created another struct and define vector<PingLogDto> and serialize this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone would have a problem like this; here is my solution:

i have just added another struct thanks to @Scheff who is my mentor now.

My new Xml Saver is like this:

```
struct Saver {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name, T const& value) const {
        auto node = named_child(parent, name);
        node.text().set(to_xml(value));
    }

    void operator()(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name, PingLogDto const& o) const {
        auto dto = named_child(parent, name);
        operator()(dto, "PingLogID", o.PingLogID);
        operator()(dto, "HardwareHostID", o.HardwareHostID);
        operator()(dto, "PingLogRoundtripTime", o.PingLogRoundtripTime);
    }

    template <typename C>
    void operator()(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name, std::string const& item_name, C const& container) const {
        auto list = named_child(parent, name);

        for (auto& item : container)
            operator()(list, item_name, item);
    }

    void operator()(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name, SendServerPingLogDto const& o) const {
        auto dto = named_child(parent, name);
        operator()(dto, "PingLogList", "PingLog", o.PingLogList);
    }
private:        
    template <typename T> static T const& to_xml(T const& v) { return v; }
    static char const* to_xml(std::string const& v) { return v.c_str(); }

    pugi::xml_node named_child(pugi::xml_node parent, std::string const& name) const {
        auto child = parent.append_child();
        child.set_name(name.c_str());
        return child;
    }
};
```

And my new struct is:

```
struct SendServerPingLogDto {
std::vector<PingLogDto> PingLogList;
};
```

I'm using this struct like this:

```
SendServerPingLogDto sendServerPingLog;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    PingLogDto pingLog;

    namespace pt = boost::posix_time;
    pt::ptime now = pt::second_clock::local_time();
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << static_cast<int>(now.date().month()) << "/" << now.date().day() << "/" << now.date().year();

    pingLog.HardwareHostID = 1;
    pingLog.PingLogDate = ss.str();
    pingLog.PingLogID = i + 1;
    pingLog.PingLogRoundtripTime = std::to_string(i);

    sendServerPingLog.PingLogList.push_back(pingLog);
}

    pugi::xml_document _doc;
    Xml::Saver saver;

    saver(_doc.root(), "SendServerPingLog", sendServerPingLog);

    _doc.save_file("SendServerPingLog.xml");
```

The only problem is in the xml we have an unnecessary tag "" thats why i had to change my server side code too.

Anyway thank you for your comments and support.

Comment: Glad I could help (considering that I still know rather nothing about [tag:pugixml]). Are you aware that you can [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)?

Comment: @Scheff It says "you can accept your own question tomorrow." so i cant now. By the way, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to add some small modification into structure, and you have C++ 11.  You can try my lib, can be found at https://github.com/incoder1/IO:

An example for you case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <files.hpp>
#include <stream.hpp>
#include <xml_types.hpp>

static const char* PROLOGUE = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>";

// optional used to open an xml file, can be cached to std::fostream
static io::s_write_channel create_file_channel(const char* path) {
    io::file f( path );
    std::error_code ec;
    io::s_write_channel ret = f.open_for_write(ec, io::write_open_mode::overwrite);
    io::check_error_code(ec);
    return ret;
}


struct PingLogDto
{
    int PingLogID;
    int HardwareHostID;
    std::string PingLogRoundtripTime; // you can use std::chrono instead

    // A meta-programming type to serialize type into XML
    typedef io::xml::complex_type<PingLogDto,
    std::tuple<>, // this one is for XML attributes
    std::tuple<io::xml::int_element,io::xml::int_element,
            io::xml::string_element> > xml_type;

    // need to be a method to be used in list type
    // and needs to be logically const
    xml_type to_xml_type() const {
        io::xml::int_element idEl("PingLogID", PingLogID);
        io::xml::int_element hostIdEl("HardwareHostID", HardwareHostID);
        io::xml::string_element pingLogRoundtripEl("PingLogRoundtripTime",PingLogRoundtripTime);
        return xml_type("PingLog", std::tuple<>(), std::make_tuple(idEl,hostIdEl,pingLogRoundtripEl));
    }
};


int main()
{
    // open a xml file to write into
    io::channel_ostream<char> xml( create_file_channel("pinlogs.xml"));
    xml << PROLOGUE << std::endl;
    // a meta type for serializing STL container of a specific element
    typedef io::xml::list_type< PingLogDto::xml_type > PinLogsXMLType;
    // a vector of structures to serialize
    std::vector<PingLogDto> logs( {{0,0,"3.1.2018"},{1,1,"4.1.2018"}} );
    // call XML root element as PingLogs
    PinLogsXMLType xt("PingLogs");
    // serialize vector, and name each tag as PingLog
    xt.add_elements( "PingLog", logs.begin(), logs.end() ); 
    // write serialized data into stream and pretty-pint XML
    xt.marshal(xml,1);
    // write same into console
    std::cout << PROLOGUE << std::endl;
    xt.marshal(std::cout,1);
    return 0;
}
```

And the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<PingLogs>
    <PingLog>
        <PingLogID>0</PingLogID>
        <HardwareHostID>0</HardwareHostID>
        <PingLogRoundtripTime>3.1.2018</PingLogRoundtripTime>
    </PingLog>
    <PingLog>
        <PingLogID>1</PingLogID>
        <HardwareHostID>1</HardwareHostID>
        <PingLogRoundtripTime>4.1.2018</PingLogRoundtripTime>
    </PingLog>
</PingLogs>
```