# C++ Add Customize XML Tag for Serializing Vector of Pairs

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

C++ Add XML Tag for Serializing Vector of Pairs

In my recently project, I want to implement a template class, this is class is very simple, it contains a vector of std::pair data. The code snippet as below:

```
template <class TKey, class TValue>
class DataModel
{
    public:
        DataModel() = default;
        ~DataModel() = default;

    private:
        std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<std::pair<TKey, TValue>>> mData = {};
}
```

My project requirement is serializing mData. I  used serialization tool in boost to implement this feature. The code snippet as below:

```
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template <typename Archive>
void serialize( Archive &ar, const unsigned int version )
{
    ar &boost::serialization::make_nvp( "Data", mData );
}
```

Using boost's serialization tool is very simple and straight forward. But one problem is XML tag for std::pair element in final XML file is controlled by boost code, and it unreadable. I want to add some meaningful XML tag in output XML file. Something likes below:

```
<item>
    <key>{KeyValue}</key>
    <value>{Value}</value>
</item>
```

Of course, boost will not serialize as above readable XML tag. Is it possible to modify my above serialization code to make final XML file contains meaningful XML tag?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not a duplicate but you can use this solution

[how to customise default Boost xml Serialisation default node naming to make it more readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050361/how-to-customise-default-boost-xml-serialisation-default-node-naming-to-make-it)